# Compare two data frames (Source Vs Target) and leave empty row if records not found in Target table (having same index number as source)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Want to compare data present in dfs "source" with 'Index' number
against dfs "Target" and if the searched index is not found in target dfs..blank row has to be printed in target table with same index key as given in source. Is any other way to achieve without loop because I need to compare dataset of 500,000 records.

Below is the source and target and expected data frames. Source data has record for index number = 3, where as target didn't have record with index number = 3.

I wanted to print blank row with same index number as source.

Source:

```
Index   Employee ID Employee Name   Age     City    Country
1   5678    John    30  New york    USA
2   5679    Sam 35  New york    USA
3   5680    Johy    25  New york    USA
4   5681    Rose    70  New york    USA
5   5682    Tom 28  New york    USA
6   5683    Nick    49  New york    USA
7   5684    Ricky   20  Syney   Australia
```

Target:

```
Index   Employee ID Employee Name   Age     City    Country
1   5678    John    30  New york    USA
2   5679    Sam 35  New york    USA
4   5681    Rose    70  New york    USA
5   5682    Tom 28  New york    USA
6   5683    Nick    49  New york    USA
7   5684    Ricky   20  Syney   Australia
```

Expected:

```
Index   Employee ID Employee Name   Age     City    Country
1   5678    John    30  New york    USA
2   5679    Sam 35  New york    USA
3                   
4   5681    Rose    70  New york    USA
5   5682    Tom 28  New york    USA
6   5683    Nick    49  New york    USA
7   5684    Ricky   20  Syney   Australia
```

Please suggest if there is any way to do it without looping as I need to compare dataset of 500,000 records.

Comment: Oh no, please roll back your edit, text is much better than images!

Comment: @IanS I did :P lol

Answer (score 1):

You can [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with `''` blank space:

```
Target.reindex(Source.index).fillna('')
```

Or:

```
Target.reindex(Source.index,fill_value='')
```

If `Index` is a column and not actually an index, set it as index:

```
Source=Source.set_index('Index')
Target=Target.set_index('Index')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way, I prefer @anky_91's way:

```
>>> df = pd.concat([source, target]).drop_duplicates(keep='first')
>>> df.loc[~df['Index'].isin(source['Index']) | ~df['Index'].isin(target['Index']), df.columns.drop('Index')] = ''
>>> df
   Index Employee ID Employee Name       Age      City    Country
0      1        5678          John        30  New york        USA
1      2        5679        Sam 35  New york       USA       None
2      3                                                         
3      4        5681          Rose        70  New york        USA
4      5        5682        Tom 28  New york       USA       None
5      6        5683          Nick        49  New york        USA
6      7        5684         Ricky        20     Syney  Australia
>>>
```